# Looking up the name and event for a ticket

Tags: php, database

This code is from my Kohana project. How can I make it more beautiful? Should I use try-catch instead? How could I avoid writing `exit()` twice?

```
public function action_index()
{
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $ticket = ORM::factory('ticket')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->find();
        if (!empty($ticket)) {
            $event = ORM::factory('event')
                ->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)
                ->find();
            if (!empty($event)) {
                $this->template->ticket = $ticket->id;
                $this->template->name = $ticket->name;
                $this->template->event = $event->title;
            } else {
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid writing `exit()` twice by adding a `return` statement at the deepest level, after passing all the checks. This should be equivalent to your code:

```
public function action_index()
{
    $id = $this->request->query('id');
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $ticket = ORM::factory('ticket')
            ->where('id', '=', $id)
            ->find();
        if (!empty($ticket)) {
            $event = ORM::factory('event')
                ->where('id', '=', $ticket->event_id)
                ->find();
            if (!empty($event)) {
                $this->template->ticket = $ticket->id;
                $this->template->name = $ticket->name;
                $this->template->event = $event->title;
                return;
            }
        }
        exit();
    }
}
```

That said, I find it a bit strange to `exit()` in the middle of a function.
It's an abrupt behavior in a program in general,
this kind of control is usually done at higher levels,
in order to do any necessary cleanup, such as releasing resources,
closing connections.